# Finding the ID of the clicked element?

Tags: php, javascript

Okay, I am not sure if this has been asked, exactly how I did, but sorry if yes.

Basically, I have 10 items in a list.

By running this query:

```
public function get10items()
{
    $this->query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM items LIMIT 10");
    $this->query->execute();

    while ($row = $this->query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo '<li id="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</li><br />';
    }
}
```

This will list 10 items from the database into '<ul>'.
This also will set an id to each item, with it's own number, like in the database.

Now, with jquery, I want the jquery to find the ID number of the clicked item.

For example our list:

```
Hello! [id55]
Hai! [id66]
```

**I clicked on item 'Hello!'.
How can I find out the ID of it upon click using jquery and then use it for future use?
For example, sending ajax query, with that id, etc?**

```
<ul class="list">
<?php echo $class->get10items(); ?>
</ul>
```

So basically I can use this:

```
$(".list").on("click", "li", function() {
    $.post("ajax.php", { get : this.id }, function() {
      blablabla
    });
});
```

Is that correct?

Comment: Your code is missing a closing double quote after the `id`. The string there should be `'">'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will trigger for every `ul` with `li` on the page. You can drill down more if the `ul` has an ID.

```
//Using event delegation since not sure when these items are being added
$("ul").on("click", "li", function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the li items like so :

```
echo '<li class = "list_item_class" id="'.$row['id'].'>'.$row['name'].'"</li><br />';
```

And then in jQuery :

```
$('.list_item_class').click(function(){
   console.log(this.id);
});
```

This will make sure only the class items will be chosen, saving you trouble later with ambiguous selectors.

Comment: It will be faster to give an ID to the ul

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

### in PHP:

```
public function get10items()
{
$this->query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM items LIMIT 10");
$this->query->execute();
echo '<ul class='someClassName' id='someUniqueId'>';
while ($row = $this->query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo '<li id="'.$row['id'].'>'.$row['name'].'</li><br />';
}
echo '</ul>';
}
```

### in jQuery:

Since you haven't posted your html code, I am delegating from `document`.

```
$(document).on('click'. '.someClassName > li', function() { // see the same class name "someClassName" is used here. 
//If you give some other class name in your PHP file, change here also.
 alert(this.id);//this.id is what you wanted.
});
```

You can also use `id` of the `ul`:

```
$(document).on('click'. '#someUniqueId > li', function() { // see the same id "someUniqueId" is used here, but with # prefixed. 
//If you give some other id in your PHP file, change here also.
 alert(this.id);//this.id is what you wanted.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery to do this is really simple:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    var id = e.target.id;
    // do your stuff with the id
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`event.target` always refers to the element, that triggered the event. 
So, `event.target.id` is the id you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
var clickedId;
$('li').click(function(){
    clickedId = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

clickedId will then contain the id of the clicked element.

Or you could use tymeJV's answer which delegates the handler to the UL parent - which would have better performance for larger lists.